# How can the ondragend be simulated when the source DOM element is removed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, typescript, angular

Greetings All

**Project Context**

We are having an issue regarding drag and drop in a HTML5 Type Script based Angular2 project however this issue is likely due to a DOM manipulation issue. In our web application we have a page in which groups of components need to be re-ordered and shifted between groups in a designer.

This 'designer' output HTML is structured like so:

```
<div>
    <div class="col1">
        <div class="group1"></div>
        <div class="group2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="group3"></div>
        <div class="group4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each 'group' defines a dragstart, dragover and dragend which handle the state of a shared dragGroup.

**Thinned Code**

```
public DragStart(source: Group): void
{
    this.dragGroup = source;
}

public DragOver(source: Group): void
{
    // Reorders the groups appropriately
    // Changes the state of the model, such that angular2 will render the DOM differently
}

public DragEnd(): void
{
    this.dragGroup = null;
}
```

**The Problem**

We have narrowed down the issue to when the group being dragged is removed from the DOM and most important bit, moved into another group.

An example of when **drag end is fired**: group1 and group2 are swapped

An example of when **drag end is *not* fired**: group1 is moved into col2

**Query**

- Why does the first example work / Why does a reorder in the same group work?
- Is there a 'best practice' way I can change the working process to get the result I want?
- Or is there a cheeky hack I can use to simulate the missing dragend?

Thank you in advance. If any more information is needed please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I have worked out a 'horrid' solution myself. As soon as someone has a better solution, I will accept their answer.

On the outer most div (the one that contains all the columns), I register 3 events to help determine the state of the mouse during a drag: `mousemove, mousedown and mouseup`.

The following Angular2 Template HTML illustrates the solution. In normal HTML it would not have the brackets around the events and would have 'on' prefixed to each event name.

```
<div (mousemove)="CheckIfDragEnded()"
     (mousedown)="SetMouseDown(true)"
     (mouseup)="SetMouseDown(false)">
    <div class="col1">
        <div class="group1"></div>
        <div class="group2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="group3"></div>
        <div class="group4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following would be the TypeScript (again, this could be easily written in JavaScript)

```
// Some storage state variable
private mouseDown: boolean = false;

private SetMouseDown(down: boolean): void
{
    this.mouseDown = down;
}

private CheckIfDragEnded(): void
{
    if (this.mouseDown)
    {
        // Call the drag end method here that should have been triggered by the drag end normally
    }
}
```

A small addition would be to check the mouse button is also a left click.